# Converting String containing Json to gSonObject

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a string that contains the following Json data

```
[{"date":"11/8/2014","auther":"nirav kalola","description":"json object parsing using gson library is easy","post_name":"json object parsing"},{"date":"12/8/2014","auther":"nirav kalola","description":"json array parsing using gson library","post_name":"json array parsing"},{"date":"17/8/2014","auther":"nirav kalola","description":"store json file in assets folder and get data when required","post_name":"json parsing from assets folder"}]
```

i want to convert it to gSon

i tried following code

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //etResponse.setText(result);
        try {
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<BeanPost>>() {
            }.getType();


            ArrayList<BeanPost> beanPostArrayList = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(result, listType);
            // Above Line gives error 
            // JsonDeserializer could not Deserialize the object
            StringBuffer postList = new StringBuffer();
            for (BeanPost post : beanPostArrayList) {
                postList.append("\n title: " + post.getPost_name() +
                        "\n auther: " + post.getAuther() +
                        "\n date: " + post.getDate() +
                        "\n description: " + post.getDescription() + "\n\n");
            }



        }
            catch(Exception e2)
            {
                    String msg=e2.getLocalizedMessage();
                e2.printStackTrace();

            }

    }
```

BeanPost.java Class is as follows

```
 package com.jobwork.mujahidniaz.ws2;

 /**
 * Created by Mujahid Niaz on 06/09/2016.
 */
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
 public class BeanPost {

@SerializedName("post_name")
private String post_name;
@SerializedName("auther")
private String auther;
@SerializedName("date")
private String date;
@SerializedName("description")
private String description;

public BeanPost(String post_name, String auther, String date, String description) {
    this.post_name = post_name;
    this.auther = auther;
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPost_name() {
    return post_name;
}

public void setPost_name(String post_name) {
    this.post_name = post_name;
}

public String getAuther() {
    return auther;
}

public void setAuther(String auther) {
    this.auther = auther;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

I have tried a lot of search on google but could not find the Answer please help me with that.

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? Is the format incorrect? Is it sad that there is no gDad?

Comment: implements Serializable your BeanPost class

Comment: @RakshitNawani Why?

Comment: Error says **the jsondeserializer com.google.gson.defaulttypeadapters could not deserialize the object**

Comment: @Zapl20 format is good. but runtime exception **the jsondeserializer com.google.gson.defaulttypeadapters could not deserialize the object**

Answer (score 0):

(Untested code)

first you must create your empty public constructor from your BeanPost.java since you have custom constructor.

```
public BeanPost(){}

Gson gson = new Gson;
List<BeanPost> myBPost = gson.fromJson(result, List<BeanPost.class>); //i assume that result is your json string
```

now you're got to with your for each to get the value. Hope it helps